# Python maintain order in intersection of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` and list `B`, I want to get common elements from the two lists but want when I get the common elements they should maintain the order of List `A`.

First I started with converting them in to set and taking the intersection but that had the problem of maintaining the order.

```
common = list(set(A).intersection(set(B)))
```

so I decided to do list comprehension:

```
common = [i for i in A if i in B]
```

I am getting

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Your error is irrelevant to your comprehension statement.

Comment: I would actually argue that this is _not_ a duplicate since the OP wants to maintain the original ordering, which none of the answers to the linked question do.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  `A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]`, `B = [2, 3]`, `[i for i in A if i in B]` gives `[2, 3, 3, 2]`. Can you provide sample data to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @AlexA. Thank You so much of not being so quick to write off as a duplicate. I think the title you used is exactly what I should have used at first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a general answer for such problems You can use `sorted` function with `lambda x:A.index(x)` as its key that will sort the result based on the order of list A:

```
>>> common = sorted(set(A).intersection(B) ,key=lambda x:A.index(x))
```

Also *Note* that you don't need use `set(B)` for intersection.

Comment: `intersection(B)` should be `intersection(set(B))` ? or you assume B is already a set..?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: As long as `A` is a set, it has an intersection method. It's legit to do intersections between sets and lists as is done here.

Comment: `key=A.index` should work without using lambda.  I think that sorting using `A.index` changes the performance characteristics to quadratic, which will make this less optimal for very large with large intersections.

Comment: What if there are some duplicates in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Your code (`common = [i for i in A if i in B]`) works just fine.  Perhaps what you wrote in your question was not the exact code that raised the `IndexError`.

You can speedup membership tests by making a `set` from `B`:

```
set_b = set(B)
common = [i for i in A if i in set_b]
```