# fastest way find the common elements of two lists without changing the sequence of first list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two lists,

```
 l1 = [1,4,3,2,5]
 l2 = [4,3,2,10]
```

Now I want to find the common element between to lists so I am using following code,

```
list(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)))
>> [2, 3, 4]
```

But its changing the sequence of the `l1`, I don't want to change the sequence so the result should be ,

```
>> [4, 3, 2]
```

Looking for the fastest way to do this without changing the sequence ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python maintain order in intersection of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755585/python-maintain-order-in-intersection-of-lists)

Answer (score 5):

You can re-sort the result using `l1`:

```
>>> sorted(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)), key=l1.index)
[4, 3, 2]
```

You could have also used a list comprehension instead of a set intersection but I believe the first method would be generally faster depending on the number of elements in each list, because searching a list is `O(n)` and the solution below becomes `O(n*m)`:

```
>>> [i for i in l1 if i in l2]
[4, 3, 2]
```

Finally, you can optimise the comprehension method by converting `l2` to a set:

```
>>> s2 = set(l2)
>>> [i for i in l1 if i in s2]
[4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Just adding some analysis- converting l2 to a set and checking l1 against it is the efficient solution, and should be used. It also maintains multiple copies of the same value if they appear in l1, maintains order, and does the minimum amount of work. The other solutions presented here are significantly slower for larger inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to preserve `l1`'s sequence. An algorithm of O(n^2) time complexity would be to find for every item `x` in `l1` if `x` exists in `l2`. Following code would work

```
common_elements = [x for x in l1 if x in l2]
```

You can reduce time complexity to O(n) by using a map(dict)

```
lookup_map = {x: True for x in l2}
common_elements = [x for x in l1 if x in lookup_map]
```

Edit: Found out that Python's `set` is implemented as a hash-map and lookups take O(1) in average case https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, so following should also have an avg. case complexity of O(n)

```
common_elements = [x for x in l1 if x in set(l2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way depends on data, but this solution should be one of the fastest

```
[x for x in [1, 4, 3, 2, 5] if x in {4, 3, 2, 10}]
```